# Calculate $1^{st}$ and last percentile without sorting data

Tags: statistics, percentile

Is there a method of calculating percentiles (even approximately) without sorting data?

I have a lot of data points and I need to find rough min and max values, while ignoring some spikes in the data, so I settled on finding the $1^{st}$ and last percentiles of the data

A sample of the data is below. It comes unsorted and there are millions of data points. In this scenario, I am trying to get min and max while ignoring the outliers, like $-0.9361269409$ and $0.004595814656$.

Is there a way I can do it using standard deviation or weighted average? Or would those processes be computationally as expensive as just sorting the data?

Alternatively, is there a better algorithm for finding approximate min max while ignoring outliers?

Bite, there may be hundreds of these spike outlier points Some of these spikes may also be adjacent to each other, so its not as simple as tracking min/max of 3 or 5 adjacent data points while looping through data points.

I am not asking for the code, just for the process. Thanks,

I saw there is a formula here to get the quantile from a table, but I can't seem to get the $99^{th}$ percentile. If I add instead of subtracting I get a value larger than the max,
https://www.statology.org/calculate-percentile-from-mean-standard-deviation/

```
-0.1623092785
-0.1623014363
-0.3849972863
-0.1623115257
-0.1622996619
-0.162292793
-0.02106845502
-0.01874575794
-0.02084289483
-0.02071095457
0.004595814656
-0.9361269409
-0.3769501916
-0.02146115653
-0.008397232259
-0.1622916339
-0.0217571923
```

Comment: That formula you referenced is only for normally distributed data. Do you have reason to believe your data follows that shape? Besides, sorting can be done in $O(n \log n)$ time, not too bad.

Comment: [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) can do this in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: @user51547 This can be considered a two-dimensional space, that can be parameterized by either taking the top p percentile of n items, or taken the top k items of n items. The latter is O(n) for constant k, but I'm pretty sure that the former is O(n log(n)) for fixed p.

Comment: If your program cannot handle millions of data points in just a few seconds, your algorithm is not just bad, but extraordinarily wasteful. Avoid severely nested loops, and you should be fine.